# Understanding random variable notation

Tags: notation

Somewhere I read:

> $X$ takes values in the set $S$, and $Y$ and $Y'$ are each uniformly distributed over set $T$

- Does "take values in the set" mean that $X : S -> ??$?
- Does "uniformly distributed over set $T$" mean $Y: ?? -> T$?
- What `??` be in both cases?

I find non formal notation very confusin

Comment: "takes value in $S$" and "distributed over $T$" both mean that the values realised by the random variable belong to $S$ and $T$, respectively. The originating set is a probabilised set usually denoted $\Omega$, endowed with a $\sigma$ algebra $\mathcal A$ and a probability measure on $\mathcal A$.

Comment: @Xi'an Unfortunately many authors use identical language to mean that $S$ is the *domain* of $X$!  In light of this, absent more context, it seems impossible to determine what the quotation truly is intended to mean.

Comment: @whuber personally speaking, I've never read anywhere "A takes values in B" to mean B is in the domain of A. It feels a rather odd way to define such relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

No, it means $X$ assume values that belong to $S$.

2)

No, it means that the values of $Y$ belong to $T$, and there they are uniformly distributed.

3)

The correct definitions would be:

$X: \Omega \to S \cup Y$ and $Y \in T$, where $\Omega$ is a set of possible outcomes for the random variable $X$.

Comment: in your point (1) does that mean that S is the sample space or the outcome?

Comment: @ramborambo sample space, that's what 3) implies.